# How to upload geoTiff to Geonode

Tags: geonode

I´m trying to upload geoTIFF files to GeoNode 2.6.3, installed in Ubuntu 16.04.
When I try I get this error:

`Could not save the layer layer_name, there was an upload error: Error while storing uploaded file::Unable to create /usr/share/geoserver/data/data/geonode/layer_name`

It used to work in GeoNode 2.4, and the geoTIFF files I´m uploading are the same ones I had in 2.4 version. I tried the upload from the web portal interface and from the QGis plugin "Geoserver-explorer". Had same error in both cases.
What could be the problem?

edit: add parts of geoserver.log

```
2017-10-19 15:26:19,059 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such datastore: geonode,landsatcr_3_re8_58
2017-10-19 15:26:19,060 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException

2017-10-19 15:26:19,078 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such coverage store: geonode,landsatcr_3_re8_58
2017-10-19 15:26:19,078 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException

2017-10-19 15:26:19,096 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such wms store: geonode,landsatcr_3_re8_58
2017-10-19 15:26:19,096 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - 
org.geoserver.rest.RestletException
```

Comment: Did you see the geoserver log for more details about this error?

Comment: I edited the question adding fragment s of geoserver.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It was a misconfiguration in the GeoNode REST role service. [This link](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/admin/geoserver_geonode_security/) helped me find the error